# Tkinter GUI: add image and change colors

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, colors

This is a Python GUI in Tkinter that opens up and allows a user to rent equipment from a company. The goal is to have the user choose their equipment type, enter number of hours to be used, and amount of equipment. Then the program calculates the total due.

I am trying to add color and picture(s) to this program. The main window is blue, but how do I add color to the second window? And how would I go about adding an image to the 1st and 2nd window?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import imageTk, Image
import os 

#Attributes for the window
root = Tk()
root.title('4 Dry Out | Main Menu')
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("4 Dry Out Logo.png"))
root.geometry("275x75")
root['bg']='blue'

class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        # Creates the frame for the new window
        self.win = Toplevel()
        self.frameFit = Frame(self.win)
        self.frameFit.pack()

        # Label that creates a title
        self.TitleLabel = Label(self.frameFit, text="e-Rental Portal").pack()

        # A comboBox that contains five types of equipment
        self.Equipment = ["Air Movers/Fans", "Dehumifiers", "Air Filtration", "Generators", "Extractors/Cleaners"]
        self.equipCombo = ttk.Combobox(self.frameFit, value=self.Equipment)
        self.equipCombo.current(0)
        self.equipCombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
        self.equipCombo.pack()

        # Asks the user for days for rental
        self.dayLabel = Label(self.frameFit, text="# Days to Rent: ").pack()
        self.dayTxt = Entry(self.frameFit, width=5)
        self.dayTxt.pack()

        # Asks the user for Equip Amt
        Label(self.frameFit, text="Amount of equipment: ").pack()
        self.equipAmt = Entry(self.frameFit, width=5)
        self.equipAmt.pack()


     # Submits the information to a module called calcTotal
        self.recordBtn = Button(self.frameFit, text="Calculate Total", command=self.calcTotal)
        self.recordBtn.pack()

        # This calculates the total amount due for renting equipment for # many days

    def calcTotal(self):
        # Creates variables to be used in this module
        self.Equipment = self.equipCombo.get()
        self.dayAmount = float(self.dayTxt.get())
        self.EquipAmt = float(self.equipAmt.get())

        # FAN RENTAL CALCULATION & PRINTS RESULT (TOTAL DUE)
        if self.Equipment == "Air Movers/Fans":
            self.fanTotal = 25 * self.dayAmount * self.EquipAmt
            self.totalLbl = Label(self.frameFit, text=f"Total Amount Due: ${round(int(self.fanTotal), 2)}").pack()
        elif self.Equipment == "Dehumifiers":
            self.dehuTotal = 50 * self.dayAmount * self.EquipAmt
            self.totalLbl = Label(self.frameFit, text=f"Total Amount Due: ${round(int(self.dehuTotal), 2)}").pack()
        elif self.Equipment == "Air Filtration":
            self.filtTotal = 175 * self.dayAmount * self.EquipAmt
            self.totalLbl = Label(self.frameFit, text=f"Total Amount Due: ${round(int(self.filtTotal), 2)}").pack()
        elif self.Equipment == "Generators":
            self.genTotal = 200 * self.dayAmount * self.EquipAmt
            self.totalLbl = Label(self.frameFit, text=f"Total Amount Due: ${round(int(self.genTotal), 2)}").pack()
        elif self.Equipment == "Extractors/Cleaners":
            self.extrTotal = 75 * self.dayAmount * self.EquipAmt
            self.totalLbl = Label(self.frameFit, text=f"Total Amount Due: ${round(int(self.extrTotal), 2)}").pack()
            

class MainWindow:
    # Creates the frame for the main window
    def __init__(self, master):
        mainFrame = Frame(master)
        mainFrame.pack()

        self.titleLabel = Label(master, text="4 Dry Out e-Rental", bg = "blue", fg = "white", font =("Montserrat", 20))
        self.titleLabel.pack()
        self.Btn = Button(master, text="Water Damage Equipment", command=self.MenuWindow, bg = "navy", fg = "white").pack()

    #Button opens a new window
    def MenuWindow(self):
        self.record = Menu()
        self.record.win.mainloop()

#Starts the main window
winStart = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wonder why you cannot change the color of second window as you know how to change the color of root window.

Comment: @acw1668 Where should I place the function for the new window? So far I only receive errors when I place the code for color in the new window class Menu

Comment: Add `self.win['bg'] = 'blue'` after `self.win = Toplevel()`.  However it will not be visible as `self.frameFit` will cover the space of the window.  That means you need to change the color of it as well.  Also you need to change the background color of other labels as well.

Answer (score 1):

To change color of a window background you can use the method configure(bg=''), here you can find an example:

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk(className='Python Examples - Window Color')
# set window size
gui.geometry("400x200")

#set window color
gui.configure(bg='blue')

gui.mainloop()
```

For the image, you can use the Image and ImageTK modules, here you have an example:

```
Import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

# Create a photoimage object of the image in the path
image1 = Image.open("<path/image_name>")
test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

label1 = tkinter.Label(image=test)
label1.image = test

# Position image
label1.place(x=<x_coordinate>, y=<y_coordinate>)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I got the coloring down, but am facing issues with installing PIL to my terminal. I'm working on a Chromebook if that matters? Do you have any tips on importing it

Comment: Or another way of adding images to Tkinter GUI?